# Is there an opposite of "gifted" as a verb?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Is there an opposite of "gifted" as a verb? For example when it's used such as "you are gifted with high intelligence". How would you say "you are (insert word) with poor reasoning skills".

Comment: I imagine you'd say *handicapped*.

Comment: I could imagine using *ungifted* to describe the opposite of gifted, but possibly not alongside "with poor reasoning skills."

Comment: @DanBron yes that would work pretty well. Thank you.

Comment: "Challenged" is the most PC antonym of "gifted".

Comment: _Gifted_ is not a verb. _Gifted_ is an adjective. And its opposite is _ungifted_ if you mean one thing by "opposite", or _slow_ if you mean a different thing.

Comment: Actually, to gift is a fine verb, and means to bestow a gift upon someone. "I am going to gift you with 100 pounds."

Answer (score 2):

We often use the opposite of "blessed" in that context:

**You were *cursed* with poor reasoning skills.**

**She was cursed with her mother's sense of humor.**